# Where does Sublime Text store unsaved files on Linux?

Tags: linux, sublime-text-2

I have an unsaved file that I am trying to locate after a crash on Linux Mint.   Where does sublime text store unsaved files on Linux OS?

Comment: If, like I believe, temporary files are stored on tmpfs for ease and speed of access, you are out of luck because tmpfs is a volatile filesystem which does not survive reboots.

Answer (score 14):

For me, Sublime text 3 unsaved content was in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`

Comment: You just saved me so much time!

Comment: How can I get individual files from the huge json file?

Answer (score 3):

For SublimeText 3, it's buried in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session` (which is a big JSON file).

For SublimeText 2, I think it's in `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings/` in one of the `.sublime_session` files.

Comment: What's the Windows path?

Comment: How can I get individual files from the huge json file?